# Do a SELECT based on a CASE statement

Tags: informix, toad, ibm-data-studio

I am trying to execute a select statement depending on the CASE

```
SELECT CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(today, "%a") = 'Mon' 
THEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM  jobs WHERE datein > today-2) 
ELSE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM  jobs WHERE datein = today) 
END CASE;
```

As a result I would expect if the day is 'Mon' (monday) then execute the Select from (monday - 2 days) and bring all the columns/rows not just 1 COUNT , ELSE execute the select for the current day.

In case the day is monday the result should be

```
id | jobs | date
1  |12,500| 12-7-2019
2  |10,800| 12-8-2019
```

In case the day is different from monday should be the same but for today's data

```
id | jobs | date
3  |35,000| 12-9-2019
```

If this is not possible is there any other method?(considering my limited access)

Database server: INFORMIX 12.1 
I can read only the database using Toad for Data Analysts or IBM Data Studio.

Comment: Please provide sample data and the output you'd like to get from that data. See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL statement?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/62576).

Comment: The query shown won't execute on Informix — the query outside the CASE has no FROM clause.  If that was all that was in the select-list (and there was a FROM clause, etc), then I'd expect to see a single number.  There is no grouping by id so the aggregates are  not grouped; it isn't clear why there are rows with date information either.  So, I think you're not showing us enough — not enough SQL and not enough schema and data.  As yet, the question is not answerable.  Please not that you should show the expected (and actual) output for the sample data you provide.

Comment: You should probably change `TODAY` to `MDY(12,10,2019)` or some similar appropriate date, to reflect the fact that in a year's time (less than that), the value of TODAY won't match your data at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a schema and data sample are hard to know exactly what you want, but if we assume that you want to get all rows from the table jobs depending on date, you can execute this query

```
SELECT jobs.*
  FROM jobs
 WHERE jobs.datein >=  CASE
                         WHEN WEEKDAY(TODAY) = 1 THEN TODAY-2
                         ELSE TODAY
                       END
```

I don't have the tools you mention, but this query run ok on Informix 12.10 and 14.10 from dbaccess.

Comment: That is exactly what I needed, you got my idea just perfectly also works as is directly in TOAD. Thank you @Jeroni